# How to align two divs with html css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to align two divs but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>ELOUANN'S SITE</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/webdev.png"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headDiv">
            <div id="headDivTitle">
                <img src="../img/webdev.png" width="10%"/><a class="trait">|</a><a>ELOUANN'S SITE</a>
            </div>
            <div id="headDivFile">
                <a id="indexFile" href="./index.html">Accueil</a>
                <a class="next">></a>
                <a class="anyfile">...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentDiv">
            <div id="rightDiv" class="content">
                <div id="rightDivDescription">
                    <div id="border">
                        <a>Bienvenue ! Ici tu vas pouvoir apprendre quelques éléments de base du HTML et du CSS, ainsi que l'accès à un memento qui te permettra d'avoir une liste de chaque éléments de chaque langage accompagné d'une description, afin de pouvoir les utiliser à des fins personnelles !</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="buttonsDiv" class="content">
                <div id="buttonsDivHtml">
                    <img src="../img/languages/030-html-5.png" width="10%"/><a href="./learnHTML.html">Apprendre le HTML</a>
                </div>
                <div id="buttonsDivCss">
                    <img src="../img/languages/031-css.png" width="10%"/><a href="./learnCSS.html">Apprendre le CSS</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my html file. I would like align "buttonsDiv" and "rightDiv".
This is my css file :

```
/* STYLE DU TITRE ET DE L'IMAGE */

body{
    background-color: #efecca;
    font-family: Bahnschrift Light;
}

body div#headDiv{
    background-color: #002f2f;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
}

body div#headDiv div#headDivTitle a{
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 250%;
    color: #e6e2af;
}

body div#headDiv div#headDivTitle img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

body div#headDiv div#headDivTitle a.trait{
    font-size: 420%;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    color: #6f6c52;
}

/* STYLE DU TEXTE DES FICHIERS */

body div#headDiv div#headDivFile {
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

body div#headDiv div#headDivFile a{
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #e6e2af;
}

body div#headDiv div#headDivFile a.next{
    font-size: 170%;
    margin: 5%;
    color: #6f6c52;
}


/* STYLE DE LA BOITE DE DROITE ET DE LA DESCRIPTION */

body div#contentDiv div#rightDiv{
    background-color: #002f2f;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    margin-right: 80%;
    font-size: 175%;
}

body div#contentDiv div#rightDiv div#rightDivDescription{
    padding: 10%;
    color: #e6e2af;
}

body div#contentDiv div#rightDiv div#rightDivDescription div#border{
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 0px #046380;
}

/* STYLE DES BOUTONS */

body div#contentDiv div#buttonsDiv div img{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

body div#contentDiv div#buttonsDiv div a{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and when i use this, it gives me that :
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/760957022686019625/760957040775397406/unknown.png
Please help me soon. Thanks you all. Bye

Comment: How exactly you want to align them? You want theme both to be centered or you want theme horizontal in a row instead below under each other? Please be more specific to help you

Comment: You mean you want to align both divs side by side(ie horizontally)? ie, one on the left side and the other on the right? If so, you can make both `inline-block` or make them `float` left & right, or maybe use `flex`. Google these words that I highlighted. You will get plenty of examples. Cheers!

Comment: your code doesn't show any attempt with float or display(flex/grid/table/table-cell/inline-block/...) or even position. What method would you like to use ?, so we might fix it or advise according to the expected result. openclassroom devrait pouvoir t'orienter aussi, ;)

Comment: please provide more information on what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a few changes:
don't use `margin-right` in `#rightDiv`. Instead you can use `width: 20%;` if you want that much width is acquired by the div. Also use `float: left;`. May be you will get your intended result.